# Disable some hours bootstrap datetimepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I want to disable selecting some hours with bootstrap datetimepicker because I want to select only time from 8:00 am to 19:00 pm.

I can't find nothing about that. Can you help me?

Comment: I'm trying get this to work as well, but without any success. I have tried:

`disabledHours: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
enabledHours: [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]`

Comment: I can report the same problem.  enabledHours and disabledHours do nothing at all.  You can try passing as array, array of strings, string with array in it, and the dozen other ways you can find all over the net, which purportedly work.  Maybe if one tries another 50 random variations one works - but the "official docs" have no examples (typical) - so it's just random guesswork.

Comment: hoursDisabled: '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,18,19,20,21,22,23' or hoursDisabled: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
$(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
    hoursDisabled: '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,18,19,20,21,22,23'
});
```

and also this:

```
    hoursDisabled: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]
```

Because in bootstrap-datetimepicker.js:

```
    setHoursDisabled: function (hoursDisabled) {
        this.hoursDisabled = hoursDisabled || [];
        if (!$.isArray(this.hoursDisabled)) {
            this.hoursDisabled = this.hoursDisabled.split(/,\s*/);
        }
        ...
    },
```

Comment: Can this be done separate for each day? I need something where someone select maybe 23 June and I have disabled 1-5am and 24 june 1-5pm.

Comment: I guess you'd ned to catch the day picked, and then disable hours as needed: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange

Comment: I tried to use hoursDisabled but it doesn't work in my side, can you make a sample in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me:

```js
$(".datepicker").datetimepicker({
    enabledHours:[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `bootstrap-datetimepicker.js` file, the disabled hours are defined as follows;

```
var hoursDisabled = this.hoursDisabled || [];
```

If you use date and time only at one place, you can simply change this `[]` to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]` in the original javascript file. But if you use date and time in several places, it is better to change the disabled hours in your html file or in a separate js file. Here's the code for that;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.form_datetime').datetimepicker('setHoursDisabled', [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best Way to perform this.....

`$(".datepicker").datetimepicker({ enabledHours:[8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22] });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can disable HourInterval

```
$(function () {
            $('#time1').datetimepicker({
                format: 'HH:mm:ss',
                pickDate: false,
                minuteStepping:30,
                pickTime: true,
                autoclose: true,
                defaultDate: new Date(1979, 0, 1, 8, 0, 0, 0),
                //this is what you will need!
                disabledTimeIntervals: [[moment({ h: 0 }), moment({ h: 8 })], [moment({ h: 18 }), moment({ h: 20 })]],
                //hoursDisabled: '0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,21,22,23',//Not Working!!
                //hoursDisabled: [00, 01, 02, 03, 04, 05, 06, 07, 21, 22, 23],//Not Working!!
                language:'en',
            });
        });
```

For more Options:
https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/

Answer (score 0):

Above posted solutions didn't actually work but this worked on every browse:

```
<input type="text" id="deliverydate" name="deliverydate" autocomplete="off" required="">
<script src="../js/calendar/jquery.datetimepicker.full.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#deliverydate').datetimepicker({
    format:'Y-m-d H:i',
    allowTimes:['11:00','12:00','13:00','14:00','15:00','16:00','17:00','18:00','19:00', '20:00','21:00','22:00','23:00'], 
    minDate:0
});
</script>
```

This disables previous date to be selected and limits time selection and it has been tested on a live website and on different browsers.